# How do I get Maps to rotate with my direction?

Tags: location-services, maps

I have enabled the **Rotates with my current direction** setting, and pulled up driving directions, but Maps never rotates with my orientation.

How does this feature work?

Comment: Which phone and model are you using?

Comment: @Arabella Samsung Focus S (i937)

Comment: Is this using the Maps app, or something else?

Comment: @rowlandshaw It's using the Maps app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it only works when you get directions. So in the bottom you can see the directions and the map will rotate.

You can see in below picture the map was turned.

[image]

You can see the same location with Bing Maps [here](http://www.bing.com/maps/?pc=W8AP&FORM=MAPXSH&cp=-30.02922~-51.22161&lvl=17&sty=r&trfc=0&sp=Point.-30.02952_-51.221224_Custom%20pin&mkt=EN-US);

Comment: @VictorCanova does that work for you? It still won't rotate for me.

Comment: @Louis Hi. Just uploaded an image. It started to rotate as soon as I got satellite signal.

Comment: @VictorCanova well...glad to see it works for someone. I wonder what's wrong with my phone.

Comment: I need to ask. Did you try another app like [GMaps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gmaps/7b8bedd5-4368-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8) and it works?

Comment: I got GMaps to do it a couple of times. Nice app, thanks for the tip. Maps did finally work once for a while, but it took like a minute to begin rotating.

Comment: @Louis Yes. Probably waiting for proper satellite signal.